# 'IDENTIFIER' rule also consumes keyword in ANTLR Lexer grammar

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, tokenize, antlr3

While working on Antlr 3.5 grammar for Java parsing noticed that '**IDENTIFIER**' rule consumes few Keywords in ANTLR Lexer grammar. The Lexer grammar is

```
lexer grammar JavaLexer;

options {
   //k=8;
   language=Java;
   filter=true;
   //backtrack=true;
}

@lexer::header {
package java;
}

@lexer::members {
public ArrayList<String> keywordsList = new ArrayList<String>();
}

V_DECLARATION
:
( ((MODIFIERS)=>tok1=MODIFIERS WS+)? tok2=TYPE WS+ var=V_DECLARATOR WS* )
{...};

fragment
V_DECLARATOR
  :
  (
    tok=IDENTIFIER WS* ( ',' | ';' | ASSIGN WS* V_VALUE )
  )
  {...};

fragment
V_VALUE
: (IDENTIFIER (DOT WS* IDENTIFIER WS* '(' | ',' | ';'))
;

MODIFIERS
  :
  (PUBLIC | PRIVATE | FINAL)+
;

PRIVATE
    :    tok = 'private'
    { keywordsList.add($tok.getText());  }
    ;

PUBLIC
    :    tok = 'public'
    { keywordsList.add($tok.getText()); }
    ;

DOT
    :    '.'
    { keywordsList.add("."); }
    ;

THIS
    :    tok = 'this'
    { keywordsList.add($tok.getText()); }
    ;

ASSIGN
    :    '='
        { keywordsList.add("="); }
    ;    

IDENTIFIER:
  tok =Identifier
  {  
   //System.out.println("Identifier: " + $tok.text);
  }
  ;  

fragment
Identifier 
    :   (Letter (Letter|JavaIDDigit)*);

fragment
Letter
    :  '\u0024' |
       '\u0041'..'\u005a' |
       '\u005f' |
       '\u0061'..'\u007a' |
       '\u00c0'..'\u00d6' |
       '\u00d8'..'\u00f6' |
       '\u00f8'..'\u00ff' |
       '\u0100'..'\u1fff' |
       '\u3040'..'\u318f' |
       '\u3300'..'\u337f' |
       '\u3400'..'\u3d2d' |
       '\u4e00'..'\u9fff' |
       '\uf900'..'\ufaff'
    ;

fragment
JavaIDDigit
    :  '\u0030'..'\u0039' |
       '\u0660'..'\u0669' |
       '\u06f0'..'\u06f9' |
       '\u0966'..'\u096f' |
       '\u09e6'..'\u09ef' |
       '\u0a66'..'\u0a6f' |
       '\u0ae6'..'\u0aef' |
       '\u0b66'..'\u0b6f' |
       '\u0be7'..'\u0bef' |
       '\u0c66'..'\u0c6f' |
       '\u0ce6'..'\u0cef' |
       '\u0d66'..'\u0d6f' |
       '\u0e50'..'\u0e59' |
       '\u0ed0'..'\u0ed9' |
       '\u1040'..'\u1049'
   ;

WS  :  (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|'\n') {$channel=HIDDEN; skip();}
    ;
```

When I try to parse the line :

```
public final int inch = this.getValue();
```

Then the rule 'VAR_VALUE -> IDENTIFIER', also consumes the **"this"** keyword, which is undesirable, since keywords also be collected into a separate list.

Is there any trick/provision in Antlr grammar to match the keywords by itself rule without effecting the other functionality like "IDENTIFIER"?

Comment: Also tried the option **`{backtrack=true;}`**, but no result.

Comment: It seams to me that the rules V_DECLARATION, V_DECLARATOR and V_VALUE belong in a parser, not a lexer.

Comment: No @Maurice Perry, these are very basic lexer rules to match the specific tokens, and then trigger the parser that contains the full Java grammar in various rules.

Comment: Oh! and MODIFIERS also

Comment: **MODIFIERS** only matches the 'public'|'private' etc kind of words, under **V_DECLARATION** rule.

Comment: BTW, shouldn't there be WSs between modifiers?

Comment: Yes, WSs should be in between MODIFIERS.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is indeed caused by the misunderstanding of what belongs in lexer and what belongs in parser:

- Lexer's job is to determine which words the stream of characters represent

  - e.g. that `this` is a `THIS`, `0` is a `NUMBER` and `that` is an `IDENTIFIER`
- Parser's job is to determine whether the sequence of words emitted from lexer conform to the given language, that is, whether the "sentence" made of those word makes sense

  - e.g. that declaration consists of possible modifiers, a type, and a list of identifiers

---

Since lexer's job is to determine which words are on the input, it processes the input and looks for **longest valid match** (in ANTLR, if two or more rules accept same input, the topmost one in source grammar wins). Not for any "most specific", but simply the longest one.

Example:

- Input `t`

  - Can be `THIS` or `IDENTIFIER`
- Input `h`

  - Still can be `THIS` or `IDENTIFIER`
- Input `a`

  - Can no longer be `THIS`, only `IDENTIFIER` is possible
- Input `t`

  - `IDENTIFIER` for sure
- Input `.`

  - No longer matches `IDENTIFIER`, so `that` will be matched as `IDENTIFIER` and the last input `.` will be matched as a new start of next token

And another example:

- Input `t`, `h`, `i`, `s`

  - Can be matched as either `THIS` or `IDENTIFIER` whole time
- Input `.`

  - Can no longer be matched by anything, so `this` will be matched as `THIS` (topmost matching rule) rather than `IDENTIFIER` and `.` will start a new token

And now to the important part - **as long as a lexer rule is referenced from another lexer rule, it's considered to be merely a fragment of the referencing lexer rule**. This means that matching it won't emit a new token, and also that it won't trigger any decisions between multiple matching tokens at the end of the fragment's match. Since `this` can indeed be matched by `IDENTIFIER` rule, the whole declaration conforms to the `V_DECLARATION` lexer rule - so unless there's another *lexer* rule that can match at least the same length of input *and* is earlier in the grammar than this rule, this rule will apply.

You didn't provide any rule referencing `THIS` so we don't know how exactly this plays out in your grammar, but the obvious cause is that lexer can match longer input or with earlier rule than anything that uses `THIS` rule.